# Django channels - custom routing does not seem to work

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I'm working on understanding Django's channel package and want to try and have more flexibility when it comes to the different things one can do on the same page. I'm stuck at trying to figure out why my webSocketBridge does not work as it looks like it should work looking at other examples.

Here is the app routing:

```
channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', ws_connect),
    route('websocket.disconnect', ws_disconnect),
    route('websocket.receive', ws_receive),
]
custom_routing = [
    route("chat.receive", receive_chat_message, command="^send$"),
]
```

The main routing that the settings.py read from:

```
channel_routing = [       
    include("ChatApp.routing.channel_routing", path=r"^/chat/stream/$"),
    include("ChatApp.routing.custom_routing"),
]
```

The consumer, not that it's even being called:

```
@channel_session_user
def receive_chat_message(message):
    log.debug("ws recieved a message")
    try:
        data = json.loads(message['text'])
    except ValueError:
        log.debug("ws message isn't json text")
        return

    if 'message' not in data:
        log.debug("ws message unexpected format data=%s", data)
        return

    if data:
        room = Room.objects.first()
        log.debug('chat message handle=%s message=%s', message.user, data['message'])
        reply = Message.objects.create(
            room=room,
            handle=message.user.username,
            message=data['message'],
        )

        Group('users').send({
            'text': json.dumps({
                'reply': reply.message,
                'handle': reply.handle,
                'timestamp': reply.formatted_timestamp
            })
        })
```

Then there is the current JS tied to all of this:

```
$(function () {
  // Correctly decide between ws:// and wss://
  let ws_path = "/chat/stream/";
  console.log("Connecting to " + ws_path);

  let webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
  webSocketBridge.connect(ws_path);

  webSocketBridge.listen(function(data) {
    if (data.username) {
      const username = encodeURI(data['username']);
      const user = $('li').filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('username') === username;
      });

      if (data['is_logged_in']) {
        user.html(username + ': Online');
      }
      else {
        user.html(username + ': Offline');
      }
    }
  });

  $("#chatform").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const $message = $('#message');
    const message = {
      'command': 'send',
      'message': $message.val()
    };
    console.log(message);
    webSocketBridge.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    $message.val('').focus();
    return false;
  });

  // Helpful debugging
  webSocketBridge.socket.onopen = function () {
    console.log("Connected to chat socket");
  };
  webSocketBridge.socket.onclose = function () {
    console.log("Disconnected from chat socket");
  }
});
```

Everything inside the `webSockedBridge.listen()` seem to do what it's supposed to, calling the `ws_connect` and `ws_disconnect`. But the part that happens on `#chatform`submit with the command thingy does not seem to work for me.

Right now it simply calls the `route('websocket.receive', ws_receive)` instead of the custom routing. What is missing to get it to use the command?

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your routing:

```
 include("ChatApp.routing.channel_routing", path=r"^/chat/stream/$")
```

Remove $ at the end.

This is my  Project structure:

```
Project/
   project/
        ...
        routing.py
        settings.py
   app/
        ...
        routing.py
```

In settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND' : 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer',
    'CONFIG': {
        'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
    },
    'ROUTING': 'project.routing.channel_routing'
}
}
```

Project/project/routing.py

```
from channels import include

channel_routing = [
    include('app.routing.channel_routing', path=r'^/chat/stream/'),
    include('app.routing.custom_routing'),
]
```

Project/app/routing.py

```
from channels import route
from .consumers import ( ws_connect,
                     ws_receive,
                     ws_disconnect,
                     receive_chat_message,
                     another_command_chat_message,
                    )

channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', ws_connect),
    route('websocket.receive', ws_receive),
    route('websocket.disconnect', ws_disconnect),
]



custom_routing = [
    route('chat.receive', receive_chat_message, command="^send$"),
    route('chat.receive', another_command_chat_message, command="^cmd$"),
]
```

consumers.py

```
from channels import Channel
import json


def ws_receive(message):
    print('Message received')
    message.reply_channel.send({'text':message.content['text']})

    print('Message.content:', message.content)
    print(type(message.content))

    print('Message[text]:', message['text'])
    print(type(message['text']))

    payload = json.loads(message['text'])
    payload['reply_channel'] = message.content['reply_channel']

    # receive the message and send to chat.receive channel
    # with command as a filter
    Channel('chat.receive').send(payload)


def ws_connect(message):
    print('Connection estabslihed')
    print(message.content)
    message.reply_channel.send({'accept': True})

def ws_disconnect(message):
    print('Disconnecting')

def receive_chat_message(message):
    print('chat receive message with `send` command')
    print(message)
    print(message.content)

def another_command_chat_message(message):
    print('chat another command with `cmd` ')
    print(message)
    print(message.content)
```

Comment: it didn't help. It still only uses the default receive route in the default ws channel_routing. Could it be because of the redis setup instead of code?